# How to share application logic only between iOS and Android using pure Dart (without Flutter)?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, ios-keyboard-extension

Is there a way how to share Dart business logic code between 2 different iOS project targets and possibly Android without using Flutter? E.g. using *[dart2native](https://dart.dev/tools/dart-compile)* or similar technology?

Ideally, the common Dart business logic would be compilable to XCode's *.framework* format that I can easily embedd into iOS app. I cannot use Flutter in my use case due to Flutter Engine's extensive memory requirements (see details below).

If it is possible e.g. with dart2native please also share the specific steps needed to be able to call Dart functions from Swift iOS code (and ideally also Kotlin Android code). Links to some good tutorial articles on that regard also work.

### Motivation / Context

I want to develop a complex custom *keyboard* that works on both iOS and Android. By *keyboard* I mean the system keyboard extension that can be used to type text in any mobile app.

I wanted to use a cross-platform framework like Flutter to share the code between both platforms. However, it is not possible with Flutter: The iOS memory limit for keyboard extension (currently 66MB) is much lower that what Flutter requires even for a Hello World app (some 116MB). Therefore, I am looking into just sharing the bussines logic and implement the keyboard UI natively on both platforms.

Comment: Did you try removing the runApp line, widgets, etc. and creating a very simple main() function with just a print line, and running this white-screen app and seeing how much memory it uses? Tree-shaking might reduce memory here. Then you can investigate the non-ui usages such as background execution to see how to run Dart without Flutter.

Comment: @GazihanAlankus This is a great suggestion but I already tried it. Without `runApp` call the memory usage decreases significantly, to 49.8MB (measured in app extension, not a normal app). While this is runnable, it is just barelly unusable as the remaining 16MB (extension limit is 66MB) is not really enought to render complex UI.

Comment: @GazihanAlankus Can you elaborate on the last sentence of your comment? What do you mean by background execution and are there some other non-ui usages? Any links?

Comment: @GazihanAlankus OK, so I tried it one more time but this time I removed every mention of Flutter from `pubspec.yaml`. And it worked! It still prints the print command from `main()` but the memory used is 24.6MB. That is not ideal but it is usable. Now I really need to know what you ment by background execution as it might be a viable path. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Rasto, I'm not sure what is the best way but my understanding here is you will have Kotlin/Swift execute at some point. From there, you should be able to start executing dart. I use this for Android and they work well: https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager_plus and it lets me run Dart when alarms occur. The link over here may also have info for both Android and iOS https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes and there is this package also https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch I think you would need to dive in to their codes. Good luck!